# Call to undefined function is_404()

Tags: wordpress

In a couple of the wordpress themes we use, our error_log is showing a "Call to undefined function is_404()"  error for index.php.  Our 404 *page* is working just fine, as far as I can see.  So...anything to worry about?   Any fix?  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is the error on each page hit, or only under certain conditions?

Comment: That usually happens when someone tries to access the `index.php` file directly,because `is_404` is a function defined by Wordpress. So don't worry too much, try to keep everything updated to avoid intruders.

Answer (score 0):

Use an FTP client to connect to your web host.

Upload the Arras theme again to /wp-content/themes/arras/.

If that doesn’t work, navigate to your /wp-content/theme/ folder and delete the /arras/ folder. This should allow you to access your site again. The problem seems to be with a widget in that theme.

You’ll have to upload the Arras theme again, or use a different theme.

or The “Fatal error: Call to undefined method” or “Fatal error: Call to undefined function” messages that reference one of your theme’s files or one of your plugins, are coming from that theme or plugin. The easiest way to get your site working again is to use an FTP client to connect to your site and delete the theme’s folder in /wp-content/themes/ or the plugin’s folder in /wp-content/plugins/.

If you don’t know what an FTP client is, then you should ask someone you trust to help you.